# ReactJS convert 2 arrays into table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays which I want to render in a table.

```js
const arr1 = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
const arr2 = ["price1","price2","price3","price4"]
```

I would like to convert this as

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>price1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>price2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>price3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>price4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: The arrays are guaranteed to have the same length.
Can someone please suggest how this can be dynamically done in React.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the rows in an array and then use it in the `table`:

```
export default function App() {
  const arr1 = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
  const arr2 = ["price1","price2","price3","price4"]
  const rows = []
  for (const [index, value] of arr1.entries()) {
    rows.push(
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{value}</td>
        <td>{arr2[index]}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Dev5 you are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are always gonna have the same length you can just use map or something similar.

```
<table>
{
   arr1.map((element, index) => <tr>
     // The first one is the nth element from the array
     // The second one we just access through index
        <td>{element}</td>
        <td>{arr2[index]}</td>
    </tr>
)
}
</table>
```

#### OR

```
<table>
{
   Array(arr1.length).map((element, index) => <tr>
          // We just access through index
          <td>{arr1[index]}</td>
          <td>{arr2[index]}</td>
     </tr>)
}
</table>
```